# Excel cut-n-paste behaviour

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I am using spreadsheets to quickly sort the garbled tables. For example, I have an address sheet with columns for region, city (republic, zipcode, address, etc.). Some cities are erroneously in the region column, so I filter out regions column to not include blank fields to quickly work on those and then cut some selected number of cells containing the city names.[image: cutting the filtered cells]

When I paste the clipboard to the cities column, even though I do not see it, the filtered-out regions (that I haven't seen) get copied to the city column. This destroy underlying city names, but I don't notice it until much later, when I suddenly discover region names in the city column.[image]

Is there a way to cut-and-paste only the cells in the filtered rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a plethora of ways to solve this problem. However, it looks like it is difficult to maintain the pasting structure of a non-continuous selection. So I would just use a worker column with cell logic:

[image: WorkerColumnExample]

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, Stepan1010, I understand the difficulty in implementation, and I see how your example works, but it seems somewhat complicated to enter formulas, while I was looking for a quick and dirty way to toss some cells around. Still, since the filtered rows are visible, there might be the way to remember, which ones are selected for cut-and-paste purposes, or so I thought. Otherwise I will stick with your answer.

Comment: I found a way that does not spoil the cells by mistake. I don't filter. I sort the rows, thus moving blanks or unusual cell content to the edges. This allows me to do my cut-and-paste stuff without damaging anything.